# How to access $rootScope value out a service function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the value of `$rootScope.exists` from the `SomeService.getData()` function. 
When I see the rootScope (using console.log) outside the function, I can see the `$rootScope.exists` value but on printing it, it says its undefined.

How can I get the value?

```
else {
    SomeService.getData().then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.1a = response.data;
        $rootScope.levels = response.data.levels;
        $rootScope.exists = checkAvailability($rootScope.accessLevels, "DataDAta");
    });
    console.log("sadsad", $rootScope.exists);
    if ($rootScope.exists) {
        $location.path('/ABC');
    }
    else {
        $location.path('/DEF');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you inject '$rootScope' into your modules array?

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($rootScope) {

}
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, I am trying to use this in my App.js file. I am not that familiar with angularjs so some more information might be very helpful. Thank you again

Comment: Hi Maddy, can you post your app.js file?